# Editing a question to provide helpful links

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976983/how-to-make-a-program-that-finds-the-number-of-happy-numbers-between-1-and-1-mil) that mentioned [happy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) without any reference to what they mean. I added a link to Wikipedia so someone who is unaware could click a link to the Wikipedia article instead of searching it on a search engine.

One reviewer approved the edit. The bot rejected the edit with the following feedback:
"This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed"

Another reviewer rejected my edit and provided his own supporting edit instead where he changed the following text:

*What's happening is that I'm trying to ...*

to:

*I am trying to ...*

I'd like to learn from the community how my edit of adding the link to Happy Number Wikipedia article was less helpful than the above reviewer's syntax correction. Mine was rejected and his is approved. Is it because this reviewer has much higher reputation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are under 2k rep, you are in need to get reviewed on your edits, so what I would suggest is every time you submit a edit try to make it as "beautiful/readable" (without changing the context) as possible.

Because, in this case, you are just adding a info link, as already mentioned in the comment, it can/may be considered too minor/not useful enough.

So, IMHO in this case:

- you might shorten the title,

from :

> *How to make a program that finds the number of happy numbers between 1 and 1 million*

to:

> *Find the number of happy numbers between 1 and 1 million*

(because from experience nobody likes big titles)

- "beautify"/indent/tidy the code (if you want you can use the tidy button from SO snippet)
- Some other minor stuff you probably would find to make this question easier to read (some bold, some syntax/semantics, spaces)
- Or, as you did you could add some extra info(not out of context) like your Wikipedia happy numbers link.

This all sum together and you have a nice edit to submit for review.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Add "remove the unrelated tag `[happy]` to your list of to-do's. Read its description to see why.

Comment: I would love for questions to receive more, smaller, atomic edits. There's a log for a reason, and a rollback feature for a reason. It would be amazing to have a full set of git-like tools for managing edits. That's completely incompatible with the review queue, though.